# Extend div beyond its parent cell in CSS grid

Tags: css

I have a problem with my UI.

I am using CSS Grid for the parent container. On-click the child/cells of the grid must expand beyond its cell.

The start point is different for each child/cell on the CSS grid but they all end up expanding on the same area/position on the screen. (`position: absolute` would be ideal for this but I can't use **absolute**)

The expansion of the child component has a transition so I cannot use `position: absolute` as it would immediately change from 'relative'(CSS grid) to 'absolute' upon applying the class or changing the `position` property effectively rending the transition useless as it would immediately 'snap' into position.

I also cannot use **negative** margin/left/right/top/bottom properties as all child/cells must end up on the same area/position on the screen despite their difference in starting point.

How do cells end up outside their cell on the same place without using **absolute**

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="jobGrid myr">
        <job-cell v-for="job in jobs" :key="job.id" :job="job" />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.jobGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10vw 10vw 10vw 10vw 10vw 10vw;
    grid-template-rows: 13vw 13vw 13vw 13vw;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```

child.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="scene" @click="toggleJobData">
        <div v-bind:class="{ absolute: absolute, expand: expand}" >
            {{job.title}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
.scene {
    border: blue solid 1px;
    background: peru;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: position 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.expand {
    transition: width 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    width: 50%;
}
```

My current code is messed up as I am trying multiple things but I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add some code? That would be helpful to answer. :)

Comment: You can calculate the total width of the parent container, and the left position of the child. Then do something like (**parentWidth - childLeftPosition**) which should give you the amount of width a child needs to expand. Then assign it to the child.

Comment: I haven't finished the code yet but it totally worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear that! I will add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the total width of the parent container, and the left position of the child. Then do something like (**parentWidth - childLeftPosition**) which should give you the amount of width a child needs to expand. Then assign it to the child.

Comment: I finally finished it, I had to use <DOMElem>.getBoundingClientRect() to get the parent-child XY coordinates relative to viewport of the **parent Grid** then subtract it from the **child cell**.

Still No **absolute** positioning, just pure relative. Finally got around this 5-day problem. Thanks again!